# Android Webview : How to catch click on the given local URL

Tags: javascript, android, url, webview

I displaying the content in the webview. Content is loaded from the server API.  Content can contain following links:

```
<a href="#register">Register</a>
```

How can i catch click on the **#register**.

I can do it with some HTML parser and append onClick event, but much better and easier will be to catch URL change to **#register**.

Many thanks for any advice.

**Edit:**

I tried the following example but without the luck

```
browser = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.intro_browser);
        // Set Chrome instead of the standard WebView
        browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url){
                Logger.d("TEST");
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                Logger.d("URL IS:");
                Logger.d(url);

                if (url.startsWith("app://")) {

                }
            }
        });
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browser.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewJavaScriptInterface(getContext()),
                Constants.Welcome.JAVASCRIPT_NAMESPACE);
        //browser.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        //browser.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        browser.loadData(htmlContent, Constants.Welcome.MIME_TYPE, Constants.Welcome.ENCODING);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom WebViewClient:

```
public class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (Objects.equal(url, "#register")) {
            result = true;
            //Do what you want here
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and then you need to give it to WebView:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```

returning `true` in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` means that you handled the Url while returning `false` means that WebView should handle it.

Comment: If you write it like this and always return `true` from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` this page will never be loaded. Why you didn't do it exactly as in my answer?

Comment: Also why you use `loadData` instead of just `loadUrl`?

Comment: But  Logger.d("TEST"); should be called everytime or not?  loadData are userd because im not loading page from URL but i creating HTML content "on the fly" based on the API response.

Comment: Yes, you are right. `Logger.d("TEST")` should be fired every time you click on the URL on WebView. How does it behave now? Is WebView content loaded after `loadData`?

Comment: Yes, after the loadData is whole view returned to the pageAdapter.

Comment: pageAdapter? Could you be more specific what happens in the example you showed above?

Comment: Get WebView by ID , create instance of the browser and set the HTML content, after that return view.

Answer (score 0):

Add an intent filter in your manifest so that links starting with "yourapp://" or something similar will launch your app.

If you are generating the web content, then generate links for your app.

```
<a href="yourapp://register">Register</a>
```

If you are not generating the content, then use webview.load("javascript:// code to replace register links to yourapp://").